# Memory Leaking Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

Alrighty, so I wrote up a binary search tree, and I'm putting it up here, the whole code (not like it's hard to find the code for this online anyways...) in the hopes that someone can find my slight error.

```
#ifndef MyBSTree_H
#define MyBSTree_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



template <typename T>
class BSTreeNode
{
public:
  T m_data;
  int m_depth;
  BSTreeNode<T>* m_left;
  BSTreeNode<T>* m_right;
  BSTreeNode(const T& x){m_data = x; m_left = NULL; m_right = NULL;}

  BSTreeNode(){m_left = NULL; m_right = NULL;}
  BSTreeNode(const T& x, const int& d, BSTreeNode<T>* left, BSTreeNode<T>* right)    {m_data = x; m_depth = d; m_left = left; m_right = right;}
};

template <typename T>
class MyBSTree
{
  int m_size;
  BSTreeNode<T>* root;

public:

  ~MyBSTree(){clear();}

  MyBSTree() : m_size(0), root(NULL) {}

  MyBSTree(const MyBSTree<T>& rhs)
  {
    *this = rhs;
  }


  const MyBSTree<T>& operator=(const MyBSTree<T>& rhs)
  {
    root = clone(rhs.root);
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
  }

  int size() const
  {
    return m_size;
  }

  bool isEmpty() const
  {
    return m_size == 0;
  }

  int height() const
  {
    return treeHeight(root);
  }

  const T& findMax() const
  {
    if(isEmpty())
      throw string("Empty!");
    BSTreeNode<T>* node = root;
    while(node->m_right != NULL)
      {node = node->m_right;}
    return node->m_data;
  }


// Purpose: finds the minimum element in the Tree
// Returns: a const reference to the minimum element
  const T& findMin() const
  {
    if(isEmpty())
      throw string("Empty!");
    BSTreeNode<T>* node = root;
    while(node->m_left != NULL)
      {node = node->m_left;}
    return node->m_data;
  }

  int contains(const T& x) const
  {
    if(isEmpty())
      return -1;
    BSTreeNode<T>* tmp = root;
    BSTreeNode<T>* tmpParent;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
         if(tmp->m_data == x)
         {
            return tmp->m_depth;
         }
         else
         {
            tmpParent = tmp;
            if(x > tmp->m_data)
              tmp = tmp->m_right;
            else
              tmp = tmp->m_left;
         }
    }
    return -(tmpParent->m_depth);
  }




  /*** ---- Mutator Operations ---- */

  void clear()
  {
    TClear(root);
    m_size = 0;
  }



  void insert(const T& x)
  {
    if(root == NULL)
    {
      root = new BSTreeNode<T>(x);
      m_size++;
    }
    else
    {
      if(treeInsert(root, x))
      {
          m_size++;
      }
    }
  }



  void remove(const T& x)
  {
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout<<" This Tree is empty! "<< endl;
        return;
    }

    bool exists = false;
    BSTreeNode<T>* child = root;
    BSTreeNode<T>* parent;

    //check to find the element to remove, if it exists, and stops at it for one of three following steps
    while(child != NULL)
    {
         if(child->m_data == x)
         {
            exists = true;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
             parent = child;
             if(x > child->m_data)
                child = child->m_right;
             else
                child = child->m_left;
         }
    }

    if(!exists)
    {
      return;
    }

    //single child
    if((child->m_left == NULL && child->m_right != NULL)|| (child->m_left != NULL
    && child->m_right == NULL))
    {
       if(child->m_left == NULL && child->m_right != NULL)
       {
           if(parent->m_left == child)
           {
             parent->m_left = child->m_right;
             delete child;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->m_right = child->m_right;
             delete child;
           }
       }
       else
       {
          if(parent->m_left == child)
           {
             parent->m_left = child->m_left;
             delete child;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->m_right = child->m_left;
             delete child;
           }
       }
     return;
    }
    //no children, leaf
    if( child->m_left == NULL && child->m_right == NULL)
    {
      if(parent->m_left == child) 
               parent->m_left = NULL;
      else
               parent->m_right = NULL;
      delete child;
      return;
    }

    //two children
    if (child->m_left != NULL && child->m_right != NULL)
    {
        BSTreeNode<T>* tmp;
        tmp = child->m_right;
        if((tmp->m_left == NULL) && (tmp->m_right == NULL))
        {
            child->m_data = tmp->m_data;
            delete tmp;
            child->m_right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {

            if((child->m_right)->m_left != NULL)
            {
              BSTreeNode<T>* leftChild;
              BSTreeNode<T>* leftChildParent;
              leftChildParent = child->m_right;
              leftChild = (child->m_right)->m_left;
              while(leftChild->m_left != NULL)
              {
                leftChildParent = leftChild;
                leftChild = leftChild->m_left;
              }
                    child->m_data = leftChild->m_data;
              delete leftChild;
              leftChildParent->m_left = NULL;
            }
           else
           {
              BSTreeNode<T>* tmp;
              tmp = child->m_right;
              child->m_data = tmp->m_data;
                      child->m_right = tmp->m_right;
              delete tmp;
           }

        }


     return;
    }

  }


  /*** ---- Output Operations ---- */

  void printPreOrder() const
  {
       PrintPre(root);
  }

  void PrintPre(const BSTreeNode<T>* node) const
  {
        if(node != NULL)
    {
        cout << node->m_data << endl;
        PrintPre(node->m_left);
            PrintPre(node->m_right);
    }
  }



  void printPostOrder() const
  {
       PrintPost(root);
  }

  void PrintPost(const BSTreeNode<T>* node) const
  {
        if(node != NULL)
    {
            PrintPost(node->m_left);
        PrintPost(node->m_right);
        cout<< node->m_data << endl;
    }
  }



  void prettyPrint(const BSTreeNode<T>* t, int pad) const
  {
    string s(pad, ' ');
    if (t == NULL)
      cout << endl;
    else
    {
      prettyPrint(t->m_right, pad+4);
      cout << s << t->m_data << endl;
      prettyPrint(t->m_left, pad+4);
    }  
  }

  void print() const
  {
     prettyPrint(root, 0);
  }

};

template <typename T>
void TClear(BSTreeNode<T>* node)
{
  if(node==NULL)
    return;
  if(node->m_right != NULL)
  {
    TClear(node->m_right);
    node->m_right = NULL;
  }
  if(node->m_left != NULL)
  {
    TClear(node->m_left);
    node->m_left == NULL;
  }
  if(node->m_right == NULL && node->m_left == NULL)
  {
    delete node;
    node = NULL;
  }
  return;
}

//function from Dr. Morales, pretty slick
template <typename T>
BSTreeNode<T>* clone(const BSTreeNode<T>* t)
{
  if (t == NULL)
      return NULL;
  else{
      return new BSTreeNode<T>(t->m_data, t->m_depth, clone(t->m_left), clone(t->m_right));
  }  
}

template <typename T>
int treeHeight(BSTreeNode<T>* node)
{
  int left = 0;
  int right = 0;
  int height = 1;
  if(node->m_left != NULL){
    left += treeHeight(node->m_left);
  }
  if(node->m_right != NULL){
    right += treeHeight(node->m_right);
  }
  if(left > right)
    height += left;
  else
    height += right;
  return height;
}

template <typename T>
bool treeInsert(BSTreeNode<T>* node, const T& x)
{
  if(x == node->m_data){
    return false;
  }
  if(x < node->m_data)
  {
    if(node->m_left == NULL)
    {
      node->m_left = new BSTreeNode<T>(x);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return(treeInsert(node->m_left, x));
    }
  }
  if(x > node->m_data)
  {
    if(node->m_right == NULL)
    {
      node->m_right = new BSTreeNode<T>(x);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return(treeInsert(node->m_right, x));

    }
  }
}




#endif
```

So, when run with this tester, I am currently memory leaking 360 bytes (according to valgrind). If there is anything else I can supply to help you find the error, let me know.

Edit: It's making 221 allocations and 196 frees.

Would greatly appreciate help here!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mybstree.h"
using namespace std;


//------------------------------------------------------
void test1()
{
  MyBSTree<int> t;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #1" << endl;

  t.print();
  cout << "Tree empty? " << boolalpha << t.isEmpty() << endl;

  cout << "--" << endl;

  t.insert(7);
  t.insert(5);
  t.insert(9);
  t.insert(4);
  t.insert(6);
  t.insert(13);
  t.insert(10);


  t.print();
  cout << "Tree empty? " << boolalpha << t.isEmpty() << endl;
  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "height = " << t.height() << endl;
  cout << "size = " << t.size() << endl;
  cout << "--" << endl;

  return;
}


//------------------------------------------------------
void test2()
{
  MyBSTree<char> t;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #2" << endl;

  t.insert('F');
  t.insert('A');
  t.insert('C');
  t.insert('G');
  t.insert('B');
  t.insert('S');
  t.insert('K');
  t.insert('U');
  t.insert('L');
  t.insert('K');

  t.print();
  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Min = " << t.findMin() << endl;
  cout << "Max = " << t.findMax() << endl;

  return;
}


//------------------------------------------------------
void test3()
{
  MyBSTree<string> t;
  MyBSTree<string> t2;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #3" << endl;

  t.insert(string("Paul"));
  t.insert(string("John"));
  t.insert(string("George"));
  t.insert(string("Ringo"));
  t.insert(string("Fry"));
  t.insert(string("Leela"));
  t.insert(string("Zoidberg"));


  t.print();
  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Testing Operator = " << endl;
  t2 = t;
  t2.print();

  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Is it a deep copy? " << endl;
  t2.remove(string("George"));
  t2.remove(string("John"));
  t2.remove(string("Ringo"));
  cout << "-- copy:" << endl;
  t2.print();
  cout << "-- original:" << endl;
  t.print();

  return;
}


//------------------------------------------------------
void test4()
{
  MyBSTree<string> t;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #4" << endl;

  t.insert(string("Pizza"));
  t.insert(string("Burger"));
  t.insert(string("HotDog"));
  t.insert(string("Shake"));
  t.insert(string("Fry"));
  t.insert(string("Salad"));
  t.insert(string("Soda"));


  t.print();
  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Testing Copy COnstructor " << endl;
  MyBSTree<string> t2(t);
  t2.print();

  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Is it a deep copy? " << endl;
  t2.remove(string("Pizza"));
  t2.remove(string("Salad"));
  t2.remove(string("Fry"));
  cout << "-- copy:" << endl;
  t2.print();
  cout << "-- original:" << endl;
  t.print();

  return;
}

void test5()
{
  MyBSTree<int> t;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #5" << endl;
  cout << "Tree empty? " << boolalpha << t.isEmpty() << endl;  
  cout << "--" << endl;

  try {
    t.findMin();
  }
  catch (string errmsg)
  {
    cout << errmsg << endl;
  }

  try {
    t.findMax();
  }
  catch (string errmsg)
  {
    cout << errmsg << endl;
  }

  return;
}


//------------------------------------------------------
void test6()
{
  MyBSTree<int> t;

  cout << endl << endl << "***** " << "Test #6" << endl;

  cout << "--" << endl;

  t.insert(7);
  t.insert(5);
  t.insert(9);
  t.insert(4);
  t.insert(6);
  t.insert(13);
  t.insert(10);


  t.print();

  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Pre Order:" << endl;
  t.printPreOrder();

  cout << "--" << endl;
  cout << "Post Order" << endl;
  t.printPostOrder();

  return;
}

//------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------
int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello Tree Tester!! " << endl;

  test1();
  test2();
  test3();
  test4();
  test5();
  test6();

  //cin.ignore();
  //cin.get();

  return 0; 
}
```

Note: this IS a homework assignment for my data structures course. I have the entire thing written up, and the output is correct, it's just memory leaking.

valgrind log:

```
==30750==
==30750== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30750==     in use at exit: 714 bytes in 25 blocks
==30750==   total heap usage: 221 allocs, 196 frees, 7,533 bytes allocated
==30750==
==30750== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403552: bool treeInsert<int>(BSTreeNode<int>*, int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40358A: bool treeInsert<int>(BSTreeNode<int>*, int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402941: MyBSTree<int>::insert(int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401301: test1() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402723: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x4029EB: MyBSTree<char>::insert(char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4014A5: test2() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402728: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403725: bool treeInsert<char>(BSTreeNode<char>*, char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4036FA: bool treeInsert<char>(BSTreeNode<char>*, char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402A2D: MyBSTree<char>::insert(char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4014D3: test2() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402728: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403725: bool treeInsert<char>(BSTreeNode<char>*, char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40375D: bool treeInsert<char>(BSTreeNode<char>*, char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402A2D: MyBSTree<char>::insert(char const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401518: test2() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402728: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403552: bool treeInsert<int>(BSTreeNode<int>*, int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40358A: bool treeInsert<int>(BSTreeNode<int>*, int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402941: MyBSTree<int>::insert(int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402623: test6() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40273C: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 18 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403BC6: BSTreeNode<std::string>* clone<std::string>(BSTreeNode<std::string> const*) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402D27: MyBSTree<std::string>::operator=(MyBSTree<std::string> const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x403154: MyBSTree<std::string>::MyBSTree(MyBSTree<std::string> const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401FB3: test4() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402732: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 48 (24 direct, 24 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x4028FF: MyBSTree<int>::insert(int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40127F: test1() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402723: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 48 (24 direct, 24 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 20 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x4028FF: MyBSTree<int>::insert(int const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4025A1: test6() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40273C: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 62 (32 direct, 30 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 21 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x402C65: MyBSTree<std::string>::insert(std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401D43: test4() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402732: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 62 (32 direct, 30 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 22 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x4039F3: bool treeInsert<std::string>(BSTreeNode<std::string>*, std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402CA7: MyBSTree<std::string>::insert(std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401E4B: test4() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402732: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 63 (32 direct, 31 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 23 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x4039F3: bool treeInsert<std::string>(BSTreeNode<std::string>*, std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4039C3: bool treeInsert<std::string>(BSTreeNode<std::string>*, std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402CA7: MyBSTree<std::string>::insert(std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401DF3: test4() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402732: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 94 (32 direct, 62 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x403BC6: BSTreeNode<std::string>* clone<std::string>(BSTreeNode<std::string> const*) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x402D27: MyBSTree<std::string>::operator=(MyBSTree<std::string> const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x401953: test3() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40272D: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== 185 (32 direct, 153 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 25
==30750==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30750==    by 0x402C65: MyBSTree<std::string>::insert(std::string const&) (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x4016E3: test3() (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==    by 0x40272D: main (in /nethome/users/-/-/-/a.out)
==30750==
==30750== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30750==    definitely lost: 360 bytes in 13 blocks
==30750==    indirectly lost: 354 bytes in 12 blocks
==30750==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30750==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30750==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30750==
==30750== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30750== ERROR SUMMARY: 13 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Note: I replaced my personal file directory information with -/-/-

Comment: Although it looks fun tracking this down, it is a problem you should solve on your own as an exercise.

Comment: I have been trying for the last several hours. :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run valgrind like

```
$>valgrind --leak-check=full ./<program_to_run>
```

you'll get a better diagnosis of the problem with the leaks respective stack. So run that and let us know the results.

Comment: Updated with valgrind info.

Comment: @Chris I'm not familiar with this error but a quick search on Google got me to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007884/valgrind-error-with-stdcin I don't know if he's right but I also couldn't track your leak down.

Comment: Possibly a false positive?